# No such file or directory error in python while looping through several files

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, unix, airflow

We are using a function to match a file pattern and if it matches we are running some jobs and eventually removing the file form the folder. But the file pattern match code is failing with "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" when the for loop is running and some of the files are removed, this is happening in so less time that we are not able to replicate the issue in lower environment. Any idea how to catch the error or resolve it. In this case 'ABCD.XAF.XYJ250.A252.dat' file was present in the folder but removed as part of some other job.

```
def poke(self, context):
        full_path = self.filepath
        file_pattern = re.compile(self.filepattern)
        os.chdir(full_path)

        for files in sorted(os.listdir(full_path),key=os.path.getmtime):
            if not re.match(file_pattern, files):
                self.log.info(files)
                self.log.info(file_pattern)
            else:
                print("File Sensed "+files)
                return True
        return False
```

Error:

```
 File "File_Sensor_Operator.py", line 25, in poke
    for files in sorted(os.listdir(full_path),key=os.path.getmtime):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/genericpath.py", line 55, in getmtime
    return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ABCD.XAF.XYJ250.A252.dat'
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It seems like you'd be better served _monitoring_ the directory for changes ([inotify](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html), [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog)) rather than scanning it in a loop.

Comment: In Airflow we have SensorOperator which sense the file depending on pattern passed to it. We have used that class and customised it to sense a file and pass that to next task. So that next task can trigger a job.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, the error is happening because after the for loop starts, you have removed one of the files which means that it is no longer in the iterable returned by`sorted(os.listdir(full_path),key=os.path.getmtime)` which then throws the error.

So I think it should go away if you change that section of your code to this:

```
all_files = sorted(os.listdir(full_path),key=os.path.getmtime)
for files in all_files:
            if not re.match(file_pattern, files):
```

That way the iterable is assigned to a variable so the state is preserved as you loop through it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, will try to use it, any idea on how to replicate this issue !!

Comment: This is not it, the problem is that the `listdir` generates a list of files, but by the time the key function is evaluated they may not exist anymore. Your suggestion does not change that.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you collect all the files, delete one, then try to sort them by each files attributes (whereof one doesn't exist anymore)

```
import os
with open("dat.dat", "w+"):
    pass
file_list = os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
os.remove("dat.dat")
for file_name in sorted(file_list, key=os.path.getmtime):
    print(file_name)
```

You can fix it by assigning the filenames and attributes to a variable before sorting.

```
import os
with open("dat.dat", "w+"):
    pass
file_list = {
    filename:os.path.getmtime(filename) 
    for filename in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    if os.path.exists(filename)
}
os.remove("dat.dat")
for file_name in sorted(file_list.keys(), key=file_list.get):
    print(file_name)
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas, but still getting the same error with this approach as well.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testpython_correct.py", line 6, in <module>
    for filename in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

Comment: you might wanna replace \_\_file\_\_ with `full_path`